# JDK compiler fails for "open" module

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

Using current JDK `build 9-ea+143`'s `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` tool, I can compile the simple (empty) example module without an error:

```
module com.foo.bar { }
```

If I add `open` as in:

```
open module com.foo.bar { }
```

...the compiler error reads:

```
/module-info.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
open module com.foo.bar {
^
```

Syntax based on http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/jigsaw/spec/lang-vm.html

Is the current JDK 9 build not up-to-date with this spec or am I missing an option to be passed to `JavaCompiler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the newest Jigsaw features, you need to use [the Jigsaw EA build](https://jdk9.java.net/jigsaw/) (as opposed to [the regular EA builds](https://jdk9.java.net)). I created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-jigsaw-reflection) exploring open packages and modules (to make reflection work) and also [wrote about it](https://www.sitepoint.com/reflection-vs-encapsulation-in-the-java-module-system/) - it definitely works on b146.

Comment: Using the Jigsaw EA build ( via command line as described here http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start ), it worked out. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Hi, I just tried basically the same (compiling an open module) and failed with the same message using the CLI and ea-builds 146 and 147.